# show and hide dynamic data of a column on button click in Vue and laravel

Tags: vue.js, buttonclick

I have a table where each row has a button 'show details'. I have another div stacked within the table, so on clicking the button I want the table to be displayed in the particular column. But I am not able to point which button is clicked from which row to show and hide the div on the clicked row. Here is my code:

```
    <table class="table nowrap scroll-horizontal-vertical">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>SN</th>
                                    <th>Ward no</th>
                                    <th>Personal details</th>
                                    <th>Social security</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr v-for="(pop,index) in population" :key="pop.ward_no">
                                    <td>{{index+1}}</td>
                                    <td>{{  pop.ward_no  }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ pop.birth  }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="#" @click="show(index)" class="btn btn-primary">
                                            Show Details
                                        </a> 
                               //show or hide div below on clicking show details button
                                        <div v-show="showDetails">
                                                <h4>Citizen </h4>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-3">{{pop.female}}</div>
                                                    <div class="col-2"> {{ pop.male  }}</div>
                                                    <div class="col-2"> {{ pop.other  }}</div>

                                                </div> <br>
                                            </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" @click="editModal(pop)">
                                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" @click="deletePopulation(pop.ward_no)">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

This is my vue code:

```
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            editMode: false,
            showDetails: false,
            population:{}
            })
        }
    },
    methods: {
        show(index){
            this.showDetails = true;
        },
```

Comment: Can you pls make a reproducible code.

Comment: Could you check again I have updated it, I want to show and hide details that is already dynamically loaded on clicking the button

Answer (score 0):

Your showDetails is global and if you click one, you click, vue will show all elements. Your code must be like this code.

```
    new Vue({
      el: '.table',
      data: {
        populations: [
          {  showDetails: false, job: 'A' },
          {  showDetails: false, job: 'B' },
          {  showDetails: false, job: 'C' }
        ]
      }
    });


<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(pop, index) in populations">
      <td><p v-show='pop.showDetails' class="Detail">My Details</p></td>
      <td><a @click="pop.showDetails = false">hide Details</a></td>
      <td><a @click="pop.showDetails = true">show Details</a></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i changed the example to detail case. You must define an attribute showDetails  in every population

Comment: population data is loaded from db

Comment: when you loaded it in vue js, do a loop for every element and add a attribute showDetails. like this: 

populations.forEach(pop =>{
pop.showDetails = false

})
you do not need to add this in the database

Comment: I did it, but showdetails value is getting changed on click but the div is not showing or hiding, it isnot getting updated in the component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213232/discussion-between-karlos-and-nistha-adhikari).

Comment: you mean this line ?        <td><p v-show='pop.showDetails' class="Detail">My Details</p></td>. Pls use this working example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-csncc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark